# use a PHP variable as the source in an iframe to play a youtube video

Tags: php, iframe, mysqli

I have spent the better part of three days on this problem. I've tried several solutions that I've found on this site but with little success. What I'm trying to do is use a PHP variable to play a youtube video in an iframe. I'm also trying to run two MySQL queries with the same input. Here is my code as it sits right now. At this moment when it runs I get the table that I'm wanting, though I still need to format it. But the iframe isn't even showing up. A previous solution I tried would pull up the iframe but inside would be an error where I was basically passing the sql query to the iframe.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "password";
$dbname     = "purpletrainer";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//echo "Connected successfully";

$trainingid = $_POST["trainingid"];
$sql        = "SELECT * FROM purpletrainer.trainingcontent WHERE trainingid = '$trainingid';";
$result     = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table><tr><th>Training ID</th><th>Title</th><th>Training URL</th><th>Training Quiz URL</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td>" . $row["trainingid"] . "</td><td>" . $row["trainingtitle"] . "</td><td>" . $row["trainingurl"] . "</td><td>" . $row["trainingquizurl"] . "</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
} else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$conn->close();
?>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "password";
$dbname     = "purpletrainer";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$videosql    = "SELECT trainingurl FROM purpletrainer.trainingcontent WHERE trainingid = '$trainingid';";
$videoresult = $conn->query($videosql);
if ($videoresult->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($videourl = $videoresult->fetch_assoc()) {

        }
} else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>

<div class="col-md-6">
        <iframe width="420" height="315" src= '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($videourl); ?>' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's common practice **not** to use the variable `$videourl` outside of the while loop. (Put your iframe within the `while` loop).
sidenote: `fetch_assoc()` will create an array. It should be `$videourl['trainingurl'];`

Here's an example:

```
<?php

if ($videoresult->num_rows > 0)
{
  while($videourl = $videoresult->fetch_assoc()){
?>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <iframe width="420" height="315" src= '<?= $videourl['trainingurl']; ?>' frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
<?php
    }
  }
  else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
?>
```

**edit for clarity and future readers**
Note that the `<?= $variable ?>` opening tag has only been properly supported since php 5.4+. When not using this version, maintain the usage of `<?php echo $variable; ?>`

Comment: The `$videourl` variable would actually persist outside the loop, it is defined in global scope, but it will contain the value assigned to it during the last iteration of the loop

Comment: Thanks @andrew, Didn't know that. Never actually thought about it like that. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks much, this is much closer to what I need. The video still isn't showing up but the iframe is where I'm getting an error that the url wasn't found on the server

Comment: @DustyHawkins Glad I could be of help. What kind of URL are we talking about here?
Make sure to add `http://` or `https://` before the url if it's an external source! (Unless it's already stored in the DB)

Comment: The requested URL /< was not found on this server. It has something to do with this <?= is there a way i can get around this?

Comment: I do not believe it has something to do with that. I believe the url you get returned from the database is wrong. Have you tried checking what the URL actually is? (simply put `echo "URL: " . $videourl['trainingurl'];` in the while loop, and see what it says)

`<?=` is just shorthand for `<?php echo`. So if you want to change that, simply turn it back into `<?php echo $videourl['trainingurl'];`.

Comment: Yep, when I do that I get URL: https://www.youtube.com/embed/lORIZ1shRIM. the reason I think it is the less that sign is that it is copied into error I'm getting in the iframe window

Comment: YAY!!! when I changed it to what you just suggested it worked. I wonder if the shorthand just isn't supported in what we have... You saved my life!

Comment: That's probably it then. I'm sorry, I shouldn't have turned it into shorthand out of the blue like that then.
Glad I could be of assistance. Again, sorry for the shorthand thing. Good luck!